# How do I convert any image to a 4-color paletted image using the Python Imaging Library?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have a device that supports 4-color graphics (much like CGA in the old days).

I wanted to use [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) to read the image and convert it using my 4-color palette (of red, green, yellow, black), but I can't figure out if it's even possible at all.  I found some mailing list archive posts that seem to suggest other people have tried to do so and failed.

A simple python example would be much appreciated!

Bonus points if you add something that then converts the image to a byte string where each byte represents 4 pixels of data (with each two bits representing a color from 0 to 3)

Comment: You're trying to do [quantization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_quantization) of the image. There's some tips here for that sort of thing here: https://web.archive.org/web/20080825200550/http://nadiana.com/pil-tips-converting-png-gif

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First: your four colour palette (black, green, red, yellow) has *no* blue component. So, you have to accept that your output image will hardly approximate the input image, unless there is no blue component to start with.

Try this code:

```
import Image

def estimate_color(c, bit, c_error):
    c_new= c -  c_error
    if c_new > 127:
        c_bit= bit
        c_error= 255 - c_new
    else:
        c_bit= 0
        c_error= -c_new
    return c_bit, c_error

def image2cga(im):
    "Produce a sequence of CGA pixels from image im"
    im_width= im.size[0]
    for index, (r, g, b) in enumerate(im.getdata()):
        if index % im_width == 0: # start of a line
            r_error= g_error= 0
        r_bit, r_error= estimate_color(r, 1, r_error)
        g_bit, g_error= estimate_color(g, 2, g_error)
        yield r_bit|g_bit

def cvt2cga(imgfn):
    "Convert an RGB image to (K, R, G, Y) CGA image"
    inp_im= Image.open(imgfn) # assume it's RGB
    out_im= Image.new("P", inp_im.size, None)
    out_im.putpalette( (
        0, 0, 0,
        255, 0, 0,
        0, 255, 0,
        255, 255, 0,
    ) )
    out_im.putdata(list(image2cga(inp_im)))
    return out_im

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys, os

    for imgfn in sys.argv[1:]:
        im= cvt2cga(imgfn)
        dirname, filename= os.path.split(imgfn)
        name, ext= os.path.splitext(filename)
        newpathname= os.path.join(dirname, "cga-%s.png" % name)
        im.save(newpathname)
```

This creates a PNG palette image with only the first four palette entries set to your colours. This sample image:

[image]

becomes

[image]

It's trivial to take the output of `image2cga` (yields a sequence of 0-3 values) and pack every four values to a byte.

If you need help about what the code does, please ask and I will explain.

#### EDIT1: Do not reinvent the wheel

Of course, turns out I was too enthusiastic and —as Thomas discovered— the Image.quantize method can take a palette image as argument and do the quantization with far better results than my ad-hoc method above:

```
def cga_quantize(image):
    pal_image= Image.new("P", (1,1))
    pal_image.putpalette( (0,0,0, 0,255,0, 255,0,0, 255,255,0) + (0,0,0)*252)
    return image.convert("RGB").quantize(palette=pal_image)
```

#### EDIT1, cont: Pack the pixels into bytes

For "added value", here follows code to produce the packed string (4 pixels per byte):

```
import itertools as it

# setup: create a map with tuples [(0,0,0,0)‥(3,3,3,3)] as keys
# and values [chr(0)‥chr(255)], because PIL does not yet support
# 4 colour palette images

TUPLE2CHAR= {}

# Assume (b7, b6) are pixel0, (b5, b4) are pixel1…
# Call it "big endian"

KEY_BUILDER= [
    (0, 64, 128, 192), # pixel0 value used as index
    (0, 16, 32, 48), # pixel1
    (0, 4, 8, 12), # pixel2
    (0, 1, 2, 3), # pixel3
]
# For "little endian", uncomment the following line
## KEY_BUILDER.reverse()

# python2.6 has itertools.product, but for compatibility purposes
# let's do it verbosely:
for ix0, px0 in enumerate(KEY_BUILDER[0]):
    for ix1, px1 in enumerate(KEY_BUILDER[1]):
        for ix2, px2 in enumerate(KEY_BUILDER[2]):
            for ix3, px3 in enumerate(KEY_BUILDER[3]):
                TUPLE2CHAR[ix0,ix1,ix2,ix3]= chr(px0+px1+px2+px3)

# Another helper function, copied almost verbatim from itertools docs
def grouper(n, iterable, padvalue=None):
    "grouper(3, 'abcdefg', 'x') --> ('a','b','c'), ('d','e','f'), ('g','x','x')"
    return it.izip(*[it.chain(iterable, it.repeat(padvalue, n-1))]*n)

# now the functions
def seq2str(seq):
    """Takes a sequence of [0..3] values and packs them into bytes
    using two bits per value"""
    return ''.join(
        TUPLE2CHAR[four_pixel]
        for four_pixel in grouper(4, seq, 0))

# and the image related function
# Note that the following function is correct,
# but is not useful for Windows 16 colour bitmaps,
# which start at the *bottom* row…
def image2str(img):
    return seq2str(img.getdata())
```

Answer (score 7):

John, I found that first link as well, but it didn't directly help me with the problem.  It did make me look deeper into quantize though.

I came up with this yesterday before going to bed:

```
import sys

import PIL
import Image

PALETTE = [
    0,   0,   0,  # black,  00
    0,   255, 0,  # green,  01
    255, 0,   0,  # red,    10
    255, 255, 0,  # yellow, 11
] + [0, ] * 252 * 3

# a palette image to use for quant
pimage = Image.new("P", (1, 1), 0)
pimage.putpalette(PALETTE)

# open the source image
image = Image.open(sys.argv[1])
image = image.convert("RGB")

# quantize it using our palette image
imagep = image.quantize(palette=pimage)

# save
imagep.save('/tmp/cga.png')
```

TZ.TZIOY, your solution seems to work along the same principles.  Kudos, I should have stopped working on it and waited for your reply.  Mine is a bit simpler, although definately not more logical than yours.  PIL is cumbersome to use.  Yours explains what's going on to do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys
import PIL
from PIL import Image

def quantizetopalette(silf, palette, dither=False):
    """Convert an RGB or L mode image to use a given P image's palette."""

    silf.load()

    # use palette from reference image
    palette.load()
    if palette.mode != "P":
        raise ValueError("bad mode for palette image")
    if silf.mode != "RGB" and silf.mode != "L":
        raise ValueError(
            "only RGB or L mode images can be quantized to a palette"
            )
    im = silf.im.convert("P", 1 if dither else 0, palette.im)
    # the 0 above means turn OFF dithering
    return silf._makeself(im)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys, os

for imgfn in sys.argv[1:]:
    palettedata = [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0,] 
    palimage = Image.new('P', (16, 16))
    palimage.putpalette(palettedata + [0, ] * 252 * 3)
    oldimage = Image.open(sys.argv[1])
    newimage = quantizetopalette(oldimage, palimage, dither=False)
    dirname, filename= os.path.split(imgfn)
    name, ext= os.path.splitext(filename)
    newpathname= os.path.join(dirname, "cga-%s.png" % name)
    newimage.save(newpathname)
```

For those that wanted NO dithering to get solid colors. i modded: [Convert image to specific palette using PIL without dithering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29433243/convert-image-to-specific-palette-using-pil-without-dithering)
with the two solutions in this thread. Even though this thread is old, some of us want that information. Kudios

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.