# How to reduce color palette with PIL

Tags: python, image, colors, python-imaging-library, palette

I'm not sure how I would go about reducing the color palette of a PIL Image. I would like to reduce an image's palette to the 5 prominent colors found in that image. My overall goal is to do some basic color sampling.

Answer (score 40):

That's easy, just use the undocumented colors argument:

```
result = image.convert('P', palette=Image.ADAPTIVE, colors=5)
```

I'm using Image.ADAPTIVE to avoid dithering

Comment: Thank you, that's wonderful. I've always hated the PIL documentation. How do you then convert it back? With `image.convert("RGB", palette=Image.ADAPTIVE, colors=5)` or something else?

Comment: This is now documented under [im.quantize](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm).

Comment: @unutbu, `im.quantize` is deprecated.

Comment: How can I specify a set of target colors to use for the color reduction?

Answer (score 5):

I assume you want to do something more sophisticated than [posterize](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imageops.htm#tag-ImageOps.posterize).  "Sampling" as you say, will take some finesse, as the 5 most common colors in the image are likely to be similar to one another.  Maybe take a look at the 5 most separated peaks in a [histogram](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.histogram).

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is to use the `Image.quantize` method. For more info, see: [How do I convert any image to a 4-color paletted image using the Python Imaging Library ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236692/how-do-i-convert-any-image-to-a-4-color-paletted-image-using-the-python-imaging-l)