# Comparing images by color

Tags: python, image-processing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to reduce color palette with PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065945/how-to-reduce-color-palette-with-pil)

I'm trying to create a program that can identify similar images based off common colors. I've been experimenting with histograms and some of the filters in PIL but I feel like I'm reinventing the wheel. So:

How can I reduce an image to X number of colors?

Comment: PIL can easily reduce the number of colors in an image. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065945/how-to-reduce-color-palette-with-pil

Comment: Voting to close as duplicate. Remember to use ADAPTIVE to avoid dithering