# Colour palette from image algorithm

Tags: python, colors, actionscript

I'm trying to write a short script that will generate and optimised colour palette from an image and eventually an array of images.

I discovered this great bit of action script code that does exactly what I need.

http://blog.soulwire.co.uk/code/actionscript-3/colourutils-bitmapdata-extract-colour-palette

And set about making a pythonic version but struggling to get it up and running, partly with how Python for loops work perhaps?

Any ideas as to where I might be going wrong appreciated.

Posting from mobile (and not github worthy yet) so here is a link to the file in Dropbox.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/lvu11zpfhjzejc0/pin_test.py?dl=0

```
import json
import math
import urllib2 as urllib
import colormath
from cStringIO import StringIO
from PIL import Image, ImagePalette

req = urllib.urlopen('http://media-cache-ec0.pinimg.com/237x/27/6f/07/276f07de404a4c9e16bcb3898bbe574a.jpg')
res = StringIO(req.read())

image = Image.open(res)
image_colours = image.getcolors(256*256)
# palette = image.convert("P", palette=Image.ADAPTIVE, colors=256)
# palette_colours = palette.getpalette()

colours_sorted = sorted(image_colours,reverse=True)

def colours_only(colours_sorted):
    colour_only = []
    for each in colours_sorted:
        colour_only.append(each[1])
    return colour_only

def similar(colour1, colour2, tolerance = 0.01):
    distance = 0
    tolerance = tolerance * (255.00 * 255.00 *3.00)

    distance += math.pow(colour1[0] - colour2[0], 2)
    distance += math.pow(colour1[1] - colour2[1], 2)
    distance += math.pow(colour1[2] - colour2[2], 2)

    print distance
    print tolerance
    if distance <= tolerance:
        return True


def different(colour, colours, tolerance = 0.01):
    for col in colours:
        if similar(colour,col,tolerance) == True:
            return False
    return True

def unique_colours(colours,tolerance = 0.01):
    unique = []
    x = 0
    for each in colours:
        while x < len(unique)
            if different(each, unique, tolerance) and :
                unique.append(item)
        return unique

print different((255,0,0),colours_only(colours_sorted))
print unique_colours(colours_only(colours_sorted))
```

Comment: I'm also on a mobile, so can't develop this into a full answer, but I'd recommend looking at PIL rather than trying to do too much directly yourself. An example of someone working with palettes is here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1065945/142780

Comment: @Neil thanks for the reply.  I've been playing around with PIL & using the convert function suggested in the other link. It has been useful for reducing the palette size but rather than reducing the palette (and loosing the true colour) I want to extract interesting colours from the image as in the example I linked to.  Perhaps there is a way to do this with PIL ?