# Python - Checking for color in the center of an image

Tags: image, colors, python-imaging-library

Hi I was wondering how to check the average color of the center of an image and take the image from a webcam.

> I looked into PIL and doesn't seem like it can access the webcam to grab a photo, or is it possible?

I found this piece of code

```
im = Image.open('image.gif')
rgb_im = im.convert('RGB')
r, g, b = rgb_im.getpixel((60, 80))

print r, g, b
```

That will check a single pixel.  I'm new to python and am wondering how to do a loop to check a 20x20 pixel square and then average the RGB.

> Also is there a simple way to determine a color?
>   (I am doing some if > and < statements with RGB right now)

Answer (score 0):

1. Crop the center part of the image which you want
2. Select the crop part.
3. Find its color by using this below code

   `result = cropped_image.convert('P', palette=Image.ADAPTIVE, colors=5)`

This output the 5 colors which are used. You can change colors=1 for one color. 
You can now use `Image.quantize` method.

Similar answer : [How do I convert any image to a 4-color paletted image using the Python Imaging Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236692/how-do-i-convert-any-image-to-a-4-color-paletted-image-using-the-python-imaging)