# Irregular color present in RGB images

Tags: image, computer-vision, rgb, image-segmentation

I am trying to implement a multiclass image segmentation task. The mask of the image is of the following kind-

[image: Mask]

I need to convert the image into labels corresponding to each class where classes are red,green,blue and black(background),which I am doing using the below code-

```
 def mask_to_class(self,mask):
    target = torch.from_numpy(mask)
    h,w = target.shape[0],target.shape[1]
    masks = torch.empty(h, w, dtype=torch.long)
    colors = torch.unique(target.view(-1,target.size(2)),dim=0).numpy()
    target = target.permute(2, 0, 1).contiguous()
    mapping = {tuple(c): t for c, t in zip(colors.tolist(), range(len(colors)))}
    for k in mapping:
        idx = (target==torch.tensor(k, dtype=torch.uint8).unsqueeze(1).unsqueeze(2))
        validx = (idx.sum(0) == 3) 
        masks[validx] = torch.tensor(mapping[k], dtype=torch.long)
   return masks
```

The issue is number of distinct colors present in image should come out to be 4 but they are coming 338 in this case, also they are coming irregular in different images too.

Reproduction of the problem could be done using the below code -

```
image = Image.open("Image_Path")
image = np.array(image)
target = torch.from_numpy(image)
h,w = target.shape[0],target.shape[1]
masks = torch.empty(h, w, dtype=torch.long)
colors = torch.unique(target.view(-1,target.size(2)),dim=0).numpy()
print(colors.shape)
```

> (338, 3)

The shape of colors should be `(4,3)` but it is coming `338,3)`.I am unable to find the cause behind it.Below is another image which is identical with the above image with respect to colors present and is giving `(4,3)` colors shape which is required.
Where I am doing wrong?
[image: Image 2]

Comment: Is your image a jpg? In that cases you may have many intermediate colours, artefact of jpg compression. Use png or tiff, which keep the exact colour of every pixel). Or pass jpg in a filter to get just the 4 colours.

Comment: Yes,I have 2 kind of images - jpg and bmp. so should i save every image with tiff or png extension or do I need to convert them in a certain way. Could you please elaborate the passing `jpg in a filter` method?

Comment: I checked the second image, and I find no artefact from jpg, but in the green lines I see an aliasing. "filter": just quantize the colours, e.g. if L < 0.2: black, if red and green < 0.1: blue, if blue and green < 0.1: red, else green. But save the result and check, maybe you should change the parameters.

Comment: I tried quantizing using the method below but I am still not getting the desired shape.https://stackoverflow.com/a/237193/6642287 .Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: i used this code to check the unique colors in both the image. """colors, count = np.unique(a.reshape(-1,a.shape[-1]), axis=0, return_counts=True)"""
print(colors) obvious that the first image had more colors. and the second image has only 4 colors. probable and quick solution/workaround  will be thresholding